# C# WPF) How to prevent controls not to be blurred in ViewBox when stretched?

Tags: c#, wpf, blur, stretch, viewbox

I'm developing a WPF desktop application. In MainWindow, there're 100 controls entirely wrapped in ViewBox.

Usually, the Stretch setting of ViewBox is None and all the controls are seen clearly as deleloped.

However, I've coded that if my appliation runs under lower resolution(of computer monitor), the Stretch setting of ViewBox is changed to Uniform to be adjusted to lower resolution. And then all controls become blurred as the ViewBox stretches to be smaller.

I've made all the setting of controls in ViewBox as SnapsToDevicePixels=true and UseLayoutRounding=true. Doing these setting is positive or negative to this case?

Is there some solution for this case?

Or, if we divide Grids into many colums and rows to accomodate each controls, does this guarantee 100% all the controls are seen clearly on every different resolutions?

As always, Thank you so much !

Comment: Someone advised TextOptions.TextFormattingMode=”Display” but result was not positive even only for Texts. My solution has to be applied to all controls including Texts. The width of resolution in my development computer is 1366 and that in test computer is 1280. So, there's no big difference.

Comment: All controls are, including Texts, it's like we see things through window glass..I think if I cannot solve this problem, the potential users of my application will not start to use my application and not stay long.


Therefore, I consider this problem with extreme seriousness.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Dear Pieter, Many thanks for your comment. Somebody guided me to remove DropShadow effect and RenderOptions and it worked fine. I used not ViewBox but ScaleTransform and it seems ViewBox is designed to play another role. Thank you !